# Spotify Web API client scope not working

Tags: spotify

I'm using the new web API and authorizes the user with `scope=playlist-modify-private`.

The user logs in and authorizes my app.

When I later create a playlist for the user I get the response `{ "error": { "status": 403, "message": "Insufficient client scope" } };`

The error is probably due to the fact that when the user first authorized my app, the client scope was lower. It seems that the new client scope is not updated when the user authorizes the change. Also, there is no option to revoke client scope at the Spotify website.

Comment: FWIW, in my tests I found raising the scopes after-the-fact does indeed work. A good way of testing this is by using the `/me` endpoint and sequentially requesting `user-read-private` then `user-read-email`.

Comment: Yes, it works for me when changing from `user-read-private` to `user-read-email`. It does not work when creating playlists, though.

Comment: I was accidentally passing a parameter named `scopes` (plural, incorrect) instead of `scope` (singular, correct). Spent more time than I'd like to admit debugging this...

Answer (score 6):

Turns out that the scope `playlist-modify` is needed to create playlists, even if the user has granted `playlist-modify-private`.

Comment: I just want to add that in order to create private playlists, you need playlist-modify-private. It's however understandable that one may think that it's possible to create public playlists with the same scope.